# Chart to take values from user from textbox.text and plot max and min values on y-axis for time in hh:mm

Tags: c#, charts

Here is the screen shot..I did what you said but now when I run the code ...the x-axis scale just goes blank ...

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = Convert.ToDateTime(textBox7.Text).ToOADate();
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = Convert.ToDateTime(textBox8.Text).ToOADate();
```

and here is the screen shot in dubugging mode, it shows some random numbers... Don't know whats that...

It's the same even if i do this:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = DateTime.Parse(textBox7.Text).ToOADate();
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = DateTime.Parse(textBox8.Text).ToOADate();
```

[image]

[image]

previous values are as shown in the fig below..
[image: PREVOIUS VALUES]

these are the values from DataGridView I am displaying on chart for Time vs Temperature...and the red circle indicates the Time values, whose Min and Max values is what I want to trying to take from Textbox7.text and Textbox8.text and display on chart X-AXIS....
[image]

Comment: WHY DO YOU TALK SO LOUD?

Answer (score 1):

By default, [`Minimum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axis.minimum(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Maximum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axis.maximum(v=vs.110).aspx) are waiting for doubles, and that's what you're doing here:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
```

But you're trying to convert `09:27` to a double which can't be done because it's in an invalid format.

But if you want to work with time, you have to set XValueType  to `Time` and parse your TextBox to a DateTime like so:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = DateTime.Parse(textBox1.Text).ToOADate();
```

And it should do the trick.

---

Using `DateTime.Parse(textBox1.Text)` will create an object with today's date and the requested Time. In your case, you're interested in keeping the date (`08/30/2016`). What you have to do is:

```
// Get the old date
DateTime currentDateMin = DateTime.FromOADate(chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum);
// Parse the date you want to set
DateTime requestesd = DateTime.Parse(textBox1.Text);
// Set the time part
DateTime newDateMin = new DateTime(currentDateMin.Year, currentDateMin.Month, currentDateMin.Day, requestesd.Hour, requestesd.Minute, requestesd.Second);
// Assign to your axis
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = newDateTime.ToOADate();
```

Comment: Thanks for the post Thomas Ayoub..But i did what you siad, but I am just getting a blank output..The time scale on my X axis is getting blank values without any scale being displayed....plz see the screenshot...I have changed the Value type to Time aswell.....Plz recommend me with another solution....

Comment: No response...Did what you said...X axis readings is getting blank when i run the code...      chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = DateTime.Parse(textBox7.Text).ToOADate();

            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = DateTime.Parse(textBox8.Text).ToOADate();

Comment: @ManuManohara which screenshot?

Comment: plz find the screen shot @ThomasAyoub

Comment: @ManuManohara what's the value of `XValueType`?

Comment: @ManuManohara and what where the previous values of `chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum` and `chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MAximum`?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub...SCREEN SHOT ATTACHED OF PREVOIUS VALUES

Comment: @ManuManohara please, stop using UPPERCASE. I don't need the values of the graph but the values of the variables.

Comment: @ThomasAyoub..sorry for that  uppercase, i couldn't notice it...plz find the attached pic that shows the values of the variables...

Comment: I shall try this and reply you @thomas ayoub

Comment: @ThomasAyoub...No its still the same...blank chart

Comment: @ManuManohara You did provided the value that you put in AxisX.Minimum in this [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tczXF.jpg). You you provide the value that were in it before you overrided it?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub...As you can see in the Pic in the Red circled area, those are the values that i am getting from the DB and those are the same values before I override with the new ones....

Comment: @ManuManohara the one cercled in red are in the date format, I'd like to see the ones in OADate format (ie:double)

Comment: @ThomasAyoub sorry I am not getting what you are asking....I am getting those values from DB onto the Datagridview and then onto the chart...and by using textbox.text i am trying to set the min and max values of only Time separating the Date from the data....i dont know what OADate does exactly, but as you has asked me to try with that so i did....